# Why isn't there an action when clicking the heart button using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to click the heart button in Instagram dm using javascript.

This is my code

```
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("wpO6b").length - 1;
var heartButton = document.getElementsByClassName("wpO6b")[elem];
heartButton.click();
```

And this is the heart button code

```
<button class="wpO6b  " type="button">
<div class="QBdPU ">

<svg aria-label="Like" class="_8-yf5 " color="#262626" fill="#262626" height="24" role="img" viewBox="0 0 48 48" width="24">
```

[An image of what happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHnHN.png)
every time I run my code, actually nothing happens and it doesn't send the button emoji.
Help me, please

[The button index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srcU5.png)

Comment: Your button will be clicked by your code, but it's unclear what it should do. You haven't shown us what click event is bound to the button.

Comment: I've added a picture

Comment: I'm sure of the class index, but for some reason it isn't clicking the button

Comment: That image is not really helpful, you have to include all relevant html

Comment: I tried to use JS to click the like button on a random picture on Instagram and it worked, did you use the developer tools to make sure that the index is correct?

Comment: I'm pretty sure of the index

Comment: ill attach a pic for the index

Comment: The picture does not show the index of the button in the array, it just shows the class.

Comment: But doesn't the index = class-1?

Comment: No, you have to find the correct index of the button in the array you get from `document.getElementsByClassName("wpO6b")`, it's not necessarely `length - 1`.

Comment: But how can i do that

Comment: Execute `document.getElementsByClassName("wpO6b")` in the console, expand the array, go through the buttons one by one hovering on them, when you hover an element it should get highlighted in the page, keep going until you find the button you are looking for.

Comment: it is the last index in the array [5], and the array has a length of 6 which is what length - 1 got me to.